# Java 8 - Locale lookup behavior

Tags: java, java-8, locale

Introduced in Java 8, `Locale.lookup()`, based on RFC 4647, allows the user to find the best match for a list of `Locale` according a priority list of `LocaleRange`. Now I don't understand every corner case for this method. The following exposes one particular case I would like to have an explanation for:

```
// Create a collection of Locale objects to search
Collection<Locale> locales = new ArrayList<>();
locales.add(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-GB"));
locales.add(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));

// Express the user's preferences with a Language Priority List
String ranges = "en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0";
List<Locale.LanguageRange> languageRanges = Locale.LanguageRange.parse(ranges);

// Find the BEST match, and return just one result
Locale result = Locale.lookup(languageRanges,locales);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

This prints `en`, where I would have intuitively expected `en-GB`.

Note that:

- if you have a range of `"en-GB;q=1.0,en-US;q=1.0"` (GB and US reversed), this will print `en-GB`,
- and if you have a range of `"en-US;q=0.9,en-GB;q=1.0"` (GB has a higher priority than US), this will print `en-GB`.

Could someone explain the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: Could you print the list of Locale.LanguageRange and tell us the result?

Comment: This is going to sound cheeky, but the printed list of Locale.LanguageRange is the same as the parsed string, "en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you provide language alternatives with the same priority, the list order becomes significant. This becomes apparent when you inspect the parsed list of `"en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0"`. It contains two entries, representing `"en-US;q=1.0"`, followed by `"en-GB;q=1.0"`

See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4647.txt

> #### 3.4.  Lookup
>
> Lookup is used to select the single language tag that best matches
>      the language priority list for a given request.  When performing
>      lookup, each language range in the language priority list is
>      considered in turn, according to priority.  …
>      The first matching tag found, according to
>      the user's priority, is considered the closest match and is the item
>      returned.  For example, if the language range is "de-ch", a lookup
>      operation can produce content with the tags "de" or "de-CH" but never
>      content with the tag "de-CH-1996".  If no language tag matches the
>      request, the "default" value is returned.
>
> …
>
> In the lookup scheme, the language range is progressively truncated
>      from the end until a matching language tag is located. …

The last sentence describes what has already said by example in the first paragraph, i.e. a language range of `de-CH` might match either `de-CH` or `de`. This lookup with fallback is performed for each item of the list, stopping at the first one for which a match is found.

In other words, specifying `"en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0"` is like specifying `"en-US,en,en-GB,en"`.

---

Maybe what you want is *filtering*, see

> #### 3.3.  Filtering
>
> Filtering is used to select the set of language tags that matches a
>      given language priority list. …
>
> In filtering, each language range represents the least specific
>      language tag (that is, the language tag with fewest number of
>      subtags) that is an acceptable match.

Thus, given your original list of selectable locales

```
List<Locale> filtered = Locale.filter(
    Locale.LanguageRange.parse("en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0"), locales);
System.out.println("filtered: "+filtered);
```

produces `[en_GB]`.

whereas

```
Collection<Locale> locales = Arrays.asList(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"),
    Locale.forLanguageTag("en-GB"), Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"));
List<Locale> filtered = Locale.filter(
    Locale.LanguageRange.parse("en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0"), locales);
System.out.println("filtered: "+filtered);
```

produces `[en_US, en_GB]` (note the prioritized order and the absence of an `en` fallback). So depending on the context you may attempt to select from a filtered list first and only resort to *lookup* when the filtered list is empty.

At least, the behavior of Java’s implementation is in line with the specification. As you already noted, changing the priority or changing the order (when the priority is equal), changes the result according to the specification.

Comment: Mentioning filter as the alternative is helpful and relevant for my case, hence my choice as accepted answer. Both Lukasz and gontard had also great answers though, which could be helpful to someone needing a concise explanation of the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The steps to get this result are as follows:

1. does `en-US` match `en-GB`? → no
2. does `en-US` match `en`?  → no
3. truncate `en-US` to `en`
4. does `en` match `en-GB`? → no
5. does `en` match `en`? → yes, matching tag found, return it

It works according to the [RFC 4647](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4647.txt):

> **3.4.  Lookup**
>
> ...
>
> The first matching tag found, according to the user's priority, is considered the closest match and is the item returned.
>
> ...
>
> In the lookup scheme, the language range is progressively truncated from the end until a matching language tag is located.

The core of the lookup algorithm is implemented in `sun.util.locale.LocaleMatcher#lookupTag`. You can check out the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/util/locale/LocaleMatcher.java#l202)

Answer (score 3):

The parse of the given range to generate a `Language Priority List`:

- for `"en-US;q=1.0,en-GB;q=1.0"` the priority list is `[en-us;=1.0,en-gb;=1.0`]
- for `"en-GB;q=1.0,en-US;q=1.0"` the priority list is `[en-gb;=1.0,en-us;=1.0`]
- for `"en-US;q=0.9,en-GB;q=1.0"` the priority list is `[en-gb;=1.0,en-us;=0.9`]

Then the lookup method follow this priority list until it found a matching locale (*according to the RFC 4647*):

- for `en-us;=1.0,en-gb;=1.0`, the algorithm take first `en-us;=1.0` for which the best matching locale is `en`
- for `en-gb;=1.0,en-us;=1.0`, the algorithm take first `en-gb;=1.0` for which the best matching locale is `en-GB`
- for `en-gb;=1.0,en-us;=0.9`, the algorithm take first `en-gb;=1.0` for which the best matching locale is `en-GB`